# how to handle the error : Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to install th enotification push with firebase react native. I setup all the environnement for iOS and i add the function to ask the permission. Until there it'ss working but as soon as reload the app i have this error :

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

apparently the permission function is the problem , but it still working because i have the console.log :
[Thu Mar 25 2021 14:08:06.506]  LOG      Authorization status: 1

alsso my code :

```
RequestUserPermission = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
      console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
    }
  };
```

and my render

```
<SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: 'black', flex: 1}}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {this.RequestUserPermission()}

          <Text style={styles.title}>S'identifier</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            placeholder="Email"
            placeholderTextColor="grey"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            onChangeText={this.handleEmail}
          />[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is throwing the error because it expects `this.RequestUserPermission()` to return a valid react child, which it is not.

The reason this happens is because you have chosen to include the call to `this.RequestUserPermission()` inside the return of the `render()` function. The `render()` function should only return valid react elements.

To fix this you should call `this.RequestUserPermission()` before returning, but from your small example it seems counterintuitive to call this function on every render, so it should probably be put inside a componentDidMount() or the corresponding useEffect hook.

Comment: On a component didMount is working fine, thanks !!!